# is there any other way i can use django @login_required parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

this little stuffs has been frustrating me since yesterday, i was trying to add @login_required parameter to my create function in django, the code works really well without adding the @login_required parameter, but bring page not found when i add @login_required.
this is my code.

```
urls.py

    app_name = 'accounts'

    urlpatterns = [
    path('signup', views.signup_view, name='signupp') ,
    path('login', views.login_view, name='loginn'), 
    path('logout', views.logout_view, name='logoutt')
```

]

views

```
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

    @login_required(login_url='accounts/loginn/')
    def jayapp_create(request):
    return render(request, 'jayapp/jayapp_create.html' )

   


 when i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/jayapp/create/

it shows
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/jayapp/accounts/loginn/?next=/jayapp/create
Using the URLconf defined in JayDjango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
```

admin/
accounts/
jayapp/ [name='list-in']
jayapp/ log
jayapp/ create [name='create']
jayapp/ / [name='detail']
backen/
^media/(?P.*)$
The current path, jayapp/accounts/loginn/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change
that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: You used `loginn` with two `n`s. Likely you should use `'/accounts/login/'`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `@login_required` decorator, you need login and logout function.

Alternative to `@login_required` you can use this if condition:  `if request.user.is_authenticated:`.